# Primefaces :textfield of parent component not updated when dialog hides

Tags: primefaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Primefaces:text field is not updated when dialog hides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479529/primefacestext-field-is-not-updated-when-dialog-hides)

Im trying to update text field from dialog box .The text field is in the parent component. But its not happening . If i give the id of text field in the update of command button . I encountered the error .
 .
Since it is not able to find the component id . I have used the alternative . I have taken the hidden field .After command button is clicked , the hidden field gets updated and through simple javascript function  im updating the text field of parent component .The javascript function is called from   oncomplete of command button in the dialog box.
Since ,as per project requirement  i have to achieve it through primefaces only not through javascript . Plz, suggest me the approach in primefaces .
Below is the code snippet:

```
    Selected Customer <p:inputText id="customerCode"
        value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerName}" label="Selected Adddress"></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer City <p:inputText id="selectedCity"   value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"  ></p:inputText>
    <ecap:lookup lookupId="LOV0072" inputId="customerCode" clickStatus="city"
        defaultDDValueIndex="0" title="CustomerCode"></ecap:lookup>

        New LOV <ecap:lookup lookupId="LOV0092" inputId="customerCode" clickStatus="none"
        defaultDDValueIndex="0" title="CustomerCode"></ecap:lookup>

    City<p:inputText id="custCity" value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"
        disabled="true" label="City"></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer <p:inputText id="customerCode1"
        value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerName}" label="Selected Adddress" ></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer City <p:inputText id="selectedCity1"  value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"  ></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer State <p:inputText id="selectedSate1"     value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerState}"  ></p:inputText>
    <ecap:lookup lookupId="LOV0098" inputId="customerCode" clickStatus="state"
        defaultDDValueIndex="0" title="CustomerCode"></ecap:lookup>
    <p:dialog id="lkpDialog" widgetVar="lpDialogVar" header="Lookup"
        modal="true" width="1000" height="600"
        rendered="#{lookupSearch.popupRender}"  >
        <h:form  rendered="#{lookupSearch.popupRender}"  prependId="false">
            <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" id="diaFrmId">
                <p:dataTable id="newfdt" var="flxSearch"
                    value="#{lookupSearch.lkpSearchCriteriaList}">

                    <p:column id="newwhc">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Search Fields"></h:outputLabel>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fdd180" id="newwdd"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.whereClause}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{flxSearch.whrClausDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="newcoc">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Conditions"></h:outputLabel>

                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="newco" styleClass="fdd95"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.operator}">
                            <f:selectItems id="newcriOperatorItms"
                                value="#{flxSearch.operatorDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="newcic">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Value"></h:outputLabel>

                        </f:facet>
                        <p:inputText id="newcriInpNm"
                            rendered="#{!flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and !flxSearch.required}"
                            styleClass="285 ftb" deferChangeEvent="true"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            maxlength="#{flxSearch.maxLength}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}" partialSubmit="true"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}">
                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:inputText id="newcriInpM"
                            rendered="#{!flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and flxSearch.required }"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            maxlength="#{flxSearch.maxLength}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}">

                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fdd" id="newbldd"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.boolValue }">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{flxSearch.booleanDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:calendar id="newcriDtNm" size="9"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and !flxSearch.required }"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}" showOn="button"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}">
                        </p:calendar>

                        <p:calendar id="newcriDtM" size="9"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and flxSearch.required }"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            enableChangeDetector="false" partialSubmit="true"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}" showOn="button">
                        </p:calendar>

                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <!-- hidden text used to update values in the parent component -->
                <p:inputText  type="hidden" id="hiddencustomerCode"  
                    value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerName}"   ></p:inputText>
                <p:inputText  type="hidden" id="hiddencustCity"  
                    value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"   ></p:inputText>
                <p:inputText  type="hidden" id="hiddencustState"  
                value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerState}"   ></p:inputText>

                <p:fieldset legend="Combined By">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="newSlctDrk"
                            valueChangeListener="#{lookupSearch.getSelectedLogOpr}"
                            value="#{lookupSearch.selLogOpr}"
                            title="Combine all search criteria with AND or OR">
                            <f:selectItems id="newSlctDrkItms"
                                value="#{lookupSearch.logicalOperators}" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <p:commandButton value="Find" id="lkpfndDg" update="resultFldSet"
                        actionListener="#{lookupSearch.search}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear" id="lkpClearDg"
                        actionListener="#{lookupSearch.clear}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:fieldset legend="Result" id="resultFldSet">
                        <p:dataTable binding="#{lookupSearch.lkpResultDataTable}"
                            value="#{lookupSearch.searchResultsForPage}"></p:dataTable>
                </p:fieldset>
                <p:commandButton value="Select" id="lkpSltRec" update="customerCode"
                    oncomplete="lpDialogVar.hide();insertSelectedValue();"
                    actionListener="#{lookupSearch.selectValue}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</h:panelGrid>
```

here ecap:lookup is the customize component

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have got the solution . The exception i have encountered is because of the form tag . The ajax event fired from the dialog is not able to find the component outside the form . So i have enclosed the page with the form tag.here is the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Selected Customer 
        Selected Customer City 
        
            New LOV 
        City
        Selected Customer 
        Selected Customer City 
        Selected Customer State 
        
        
            -->

```
                    <p:column id="newwhc">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Search Fields"></h:outputLabel>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fdd180" id="newwdd"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.whereClause}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{flxSearch.whrClausDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="newcoc">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Conditions"></h:outputLabel>

                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="newco" styleClass="fdd95"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.operator}">
                            <f:selectItems id="newcriOperatorItms"
                                value="#{flxSearch.operatorDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="newcic">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Value"></h:outputLabel>

                        </f:facet>
                        <p:inputText id="newcriInpNm"
                            rendered="#{!flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and !flxSearch.required}"
                            styleClass="285 ftb" deferChangeEvent="true"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            maxlength="#{flxSearch.maxLength}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}" partialSubmit="true"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}">
                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:inputText id="newcriInpM"
                            rendered="#{!flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and flxSearch.required }"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            maxlength="#{flxSearch.maxLength}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}">

                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fdd" id="newbldd"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.boolValue }">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{flxSearch.booleanDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:calendar id="newcriDtNm" size="9"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and !flxSearch.required }"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}" showOn="button"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}">
                        </p:calendar>

                        <p:calendar id="newcriDtM" size="9"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and flxSearch.required }"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            enableChangeDetector="false" partialSubmit="true"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}" showOn="button">
                        </p:calendar>

                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                  <p:fieldset legend="Combined By">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="newSlctDrk"
                            valueChangeListener="#{lookupSearch.getSelectedLogOpr}"
                            value="#{lookupSearch.selLogOpr}"
                            title="Combine all search criteria with AND or OR">
                            <f:selectItems id="newSlctDrkItms"
                                value="#{lookupSearch.logicalOperators}" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <p:commandButton value="Find" id="lkpfndDg" update="resultFldSet"
                        actionListener="#{lookupSearch.search}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear" id="lkpClearDg"
                        actionListener="#{lookupSearch.clear}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:fieldset legend="Result" id="resultFldSet">
                        <p:dataTable binding="#{lookupSearch.lkpResultDataTable}"
                            value="#{lookupSearch.searchResultsForPage}"></p:dataTable>
                </p:fieldset>
                <p:commandButton value="Select" id="lkpSltRec" update="customerCode,customerCode1,selectedCity1,selectedSate1"
                    oncomplete="lpDialogVar.hide();insertSelectedValue();"
                    actionListener="#{lookupSearch.selectValue}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        <!-- </h:form>-->
    </p:dialog>

</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```