# Primefaces:text field is not updated when dialog hides

Tags: primefaces

Im trying to update text field from dialog box .The text field is in the parent component. But its not happening . If i give the id of text field in the update of command button . I encountered the error :
**javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "customerCode" referenced from "tabView:lkpSltRec"**

Since it is not able to find the component id . I have used the alternative . I have taken the hidden field .After command button is clicked , the hidden field gets updated and through simple javascript function im updating the text field of parent component .The javascript function is called from oncomplete of command button in the dialog box. Since ,as per project requirement i have to achieve it through primefaces only not through javascript . Plz, suggest me the approach in primefaces . Below is the code snippet:

Here ecap:lookup is the the customize component.

```
    Selected Customer <p:inputText id="customerCode"
        value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerName}" label="Selected Adddress"></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer City <p:inputText id="selectedCity"   value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"  ></p:inputText>
    <ecap:lookup lookupId="LOV0072" inputId="customerCode" clickStatus="city"
        defaultDDValueIndex="0" title="CustomerCode"></ecap:lookup>

        New LOV <ecap:lookup lookupId="LOV0092" inputId="customerCode" clickStatus="none"
        defaultDDValueIndex="0" title="CustomerCode"></ecap:lookup>

    City<p:inputText id="custCity" value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"
        disabled="true" label="City"></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer <p:inputText id="customerCode1"
        value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerName}" label="Selected Adddress" ></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer City <p:inputText id="selectedCity1"  value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"  ></p:inputText>
    Selected Customer State <p:inputText id="selectedSate1"     value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerState}"  ></p:inputText>
    <ecap:lookup lookupId="LOV0098" inputId="customerCode" clickStatus="state"
        defaultDDValueIndex="0" title="CustomerCode"></ecap:lookup>
    <p:dialog id="lkpDialog" widgetVar="lpDialogVar" header="Lookup"
        modal="true" width="1000" height="600"
        rendered="#{lookupSearch.popupRender}"  >
        <h:form  rendered="#{lookupSearch.popupRender}"  prependId="false">
            <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" id="diaFrmId">
                <p:dataTable id="newfdt" var="flxSearch"
                    value="#{lookupSearch.lkpSearchCriteriaList}">

                    <p:column id="newwhc">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Search Fields"></h:outputLabel>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fdd180" id="newwdd"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.whereClause}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{flxSearch.whrClausDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="newcoc">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Conditions"></h:outputLabel>

                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="newco" styleClass="fdd95"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.operator}">
                            <f:selectItems id="newcriOperatorItms"
                                value="#{flxSearch.operatorDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="newcic">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Value"></h:outputLabel>

                        </f:facet>
                        <p:inputText id="newcriInpNm"
                            rendered="#{!flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and !flxSearch.required}"
                            styleClass="285 ftb" deferChangeEvent="true"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            maxlength="#{flxSearch.maxLength}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}" partialSubmit="true"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}">
                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:inputText id="newcriInpM"
                            rendered="#{!flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and flxSearch.required }"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            maxlength="#{flxSearch.maxLength}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}">

                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fdd" id="newbldd"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.boolValue }">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{flxSearch.booleanDropdown}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:calendar id="newcriDtNm" size="9"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and !flxSearch.required }"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}" showOn="button"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}">
                        </p:calendar>

                        <p:calendar id="newcriDtM" size="9"
                            rendered="#{flxSearch.inputDate and !flxSearch.boolValue and flxSearch.required }"
                            disabled="#{flxSearch.disableInput}"
                            value="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.value}"
                            enableChangeDetector="false" partialSubmit="true"
                            labelValue="#{flxSearch.searchCriterion.label}"
                            required="#{flxSearch.required}" showOn="button">
                        </p:calendar>

                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <!-- hidden text used to update values in the parent component -->
                <p:inputText  type="hidden" id="hiddencustomerCode"  
                    value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerName}"   ></p:inputText>
                <p:inputText  type="hidden" id="hiddencustCity"  
                    value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerCity}"   ></p:inputText>
                <p:inputText  type="hidden" id="hiddencustState"  
                value="#{sixthTabBBean.customerState}"   ></p:inputText>

                <p:fieldset legend="Combined By">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="newSlctDrk"
                            valueChangeListener="#{lookupSearch.getSelectedLogOpr}"
                            value="#{lookupSearch.selLogOpr}"
                            title="Combine all search criteria with AND or OR">
                            <f:selectItems id="newSlctDrkItms"
                                value="#{lookupSearch.logicalOperators}" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <p:commandButton value="Find" id="lkpfndDg" update="resultFldSet"
                        actionListener="#{lookupSearch.search}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear" id="lkpClearDg"
                        actionListener="#{lookupSearch.clear}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:fieldset legend="Result" id="resultFldSet">
                        <p:dataTable binding="#{lookupSearch.lkpResultDataTable}"
                            value="#{lookupSearch.searchResultsForPage}"></p:dataTable>
                </p:fieldset>
                <p:commandButton value="Select" id="lkpSltRec" update="customerCode"
                    oncomplete="lpDialogVar.hide();insertSelectedValue();"
                    actionListener="#{lookupSearch.selectValue}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</h:panelGrid>
```

Here ecap:lookup is the customize component.

Comment: _If i give the id of text field in the update of command button . I encountered the error:_ And how did you referenced the `ID` ? If you put it like this `update="customerCode"` then it won't work because your `commandButton` is inside the another `form`. Try to reference it in this way `update=":customerCode"` (**:** added) so you actually step outside the form and search for the `ID="customerCode"`. Also I assume that you don't have `inputText` wrapped with `form` because of needs of your custom component, otherwise they won't get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have got the solution . The exception i have encountered is because of the form tag . The ajax event fired from the dialog is  not able to find the component outside the form .In this case use:
:#{p:component('componentId')}

Here it will search the id not only within the form but outside of it.